# Defining a rhomb by two triangles

Tags: python, python-3.x

First I define two functions. One that makes a triangle with odd (3,5,7...) base *b* upwards and placed *a* units away from the left side. Then another one that does the same with but with a triangle with the base downwards. Call them triup and trido respectively. We get:

```
def triup(a,b):
    c=b
    a=a 
    for i in range(1,b+1):
        print(a*" "+c*'*')
        c-=2
        a+=1
        if c==-1:
           break

def trido(a,b):
    c=1
    a=a+round((b-1)/2)
    for j in range(1,b+1):
        print(a*" "+c*"*")
        c+=2
        a-=1
        if c==b+2:
            break
```

Now I want to make a rhomb by combining the two functions. So first I tried:

```
def rhomb(a,b):
    print(trido(a,b))
    print(triup(a,b))
```

Which prints "None" two times. Also I have to change so that I do not the base two times, but I cannot change the definition of the triangles. How do I go about to solve that? Any tips will be useful

Comment: Your functions return nothing so return None by default, don't print the function calls and the nones wont appear

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I've tried return as well. But then the rhomb function just prints the first "result" from the trido loop and the first "result" from the triup loop.

Comment: You cannot return in the loop, if you want to join both outputs then concat each string and return the concatenated string instead of your break

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to return values if you want to use the strings later, concatenate each string you are printing in your code adding a newline, by returning actual value you will also remove the None's you see in your output as you are not actually returning a value not the python default None.:

```
def triup(a, b):
    c = b
    out = ""
    for i in range(1, b + 1):
        out += a * " " + c * '*' + "\n"
        c -= 2
        a += 1
        if c == -1:
            return out
    return  out


def trido(a, b):
    c = 1
    a += round((b - 1) / 2)
    out = ""
    for j in range(1, b + 1):
        out += a * " " + c * "*"  + "\n"
        c += 2
        a -= 1
        if c == b + 2:
            return out
    return out
```

You can store both outputs and do whatever you like with them:

```
In [10]: a,b = triup(5,5),trido(5,5)

In [11]: print(a)
     *****
      ***
       *


In [12]: print(b)
       *
      ***
     *****


In [13]: print(b+a)
       *
      ***
     *****
     *****
      ***
       *
In [14]: print(a + b)
     *****
      ***
       *
       *
      ***
     *****
```

Comment: Thank you! Can you explain "out"? Is there a way to print either triup or trido without the base (so that it doesn't repeat in the rhomb)?

Comment: Here is how I tried: 
def rhomb(a,b):
    print(trido(a,b)+" "+triup(a,b-2))
The added space only applies to the first line of triup though. How can I fix that?